# how to change TintColor of backBarButton in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios

How can I change the color of backBarButton, when I navigate from one view to another?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Thanx but it is not working, when I use a separate class for navigationController then it works but in the condition when in portrait mode I click on PopOver View then after rotation it doesn't work, I am using SplitViewController.

Comment: The popover is a special case. You can't change the color of the enclosing frame. In this case, you can only add a custom view to the navigation bar to look like something you need.